# How to access the entity converted from php to javascript object

Tags: php, json, doctrine-orm

I am throwing entity object to javascript by ajax

in php

```
// obtaining object by doctrine2
$lesson = $em->getRepository('Lesson')
    ->findOneBy(array('id' => $myId));

// $lesson->getName(); // I can access the entity property here like this.

//throwing object as json
$response = array("responseCode" => 200,'lesson' => $lesson,"success" => true);
return new Response(json_encode($response),200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
```

in javascript

```
function reloadItems(){
    var url= "http://myajax.com/ajax/";
    $.post(url,something,function(data){
// I got lesson object from php as json here.

// however these doesn't work
//      console.log(data.lesson.name);
//      console.log(data.lesson.getName);

    });
```

How can I get the each repository data in javascript??

Comment: just `console.log(data.lesson)` and check the console browser, to get a proper outlook of the response, you should add it on the question

Comment: console.log(data.lesson); shows  ' Object {} ' on Chrome.

Comment: odd, check out the network tab and check for the response, and just check `console.log(data)`, also debug PHP if its empty or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passed an object, json_encode can only grab the public properties.  Methods are ignored completely.  Since $lesson is a doctrine entity then I'm sure Lesson::name is either private or protected.

There are some serializer tools like http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html which use reflection to access private/protected variables.

Or you can use PHP's (>=5.4) json serializer http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php

Something like:

```
class Lesson implements \JsonSerializable
{
  private $name;

  public function jsonSerialize() 
  {
    return 
    [
      'name' => $this->name,
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: I understood basically, can't convert  php method to json object. I will research work around way you mentioned. thanks!!